# DisMax to parse user queries and q or fq to filter results

Tags: php, solr

I am using PHP to grab user search queries and running them through SOLR on a specific field "keyword" which contains essentially a concatenation of all of the data in the document.

I am also using facets on this query to further drill down on the result set.

My questions:

1. Should I be using SOLR DisMax to parse ALL user query?
2. Is it considered bad practice to put the faceted drill-down searches
   directly into a standard query with the keyword search OR should I be using
   filterqueries to filter the original standard query and it's resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `eDisMax`, it's basically more powerful and more tolerant (it means it usually doesn't return errors for malformed queries).

I'd strongly recommend to use [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to filter your results (`fq` parameter) clicking for example  on a facet entry, mainly for these reasons:

- filter queries don't influence the solr score
- filter queries are faster, since cached independently from the main query through the [filter cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache)

Answer (score 2):

The choice of query parser depends upon your requirement. [Should_I_use_the_standard_or_dismax_Query_Parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Should_I_use_the_standard_or_dismax_Query_Parser)

Dismax/Edismax allows you to query and boost on multiple fields, but has some limitations with handling of operators and their support.
If you are querying on a single field, Standard query parser can serve the requirement.

And as mentioned by @javanna
You should always try to use filter queries as against the search on the keywords, as it allows [filtering with cache support](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache).